# How to use height: -webkit-fill-available in Edge browser? How to make a div fill the available space in Edge?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I am using bootstrap to preview the mobile device as follows:
[image]

It works perfectly fine in Chrome. But not on edge :(

My HTML/CSS code is as follows:

```css
.frame {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #b3b6b9;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 50px 10px 75px 10px;
}

.screen {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  padding: 20px 15px 150px 15px;
  
}
.circle {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.preview {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;

  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;

  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #dee0e2;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p>Preview</p>
          <div class="frame">
            <div class="screen">
              <div class="preview"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle">
              &nbsp;
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But the layout is not working fine in Edge. I guess there is something to do with the CSS statement height: -webkit-fill-available;

The layout of the mobile device in Edge is shown below for your reference.
[image]

Notice that the preview div also not displayed in Edge:

Comment: Just like Balaji731 has suggested, when you add some content to preview you will see the div. This is because for example, Chrome will give a default height to the div but Edge could not. But the div is really existing.

Answer (score 17):

I think you can simply declare height twice:

```
height: 100%;
height: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
height: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
height: fill-available;
```

Comment: But the preview div is not displaying in Edge

Comment: after adding height 100% to preview. I am able to see the preview in edge. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Need to set the `height:100%` for `.screen` container.
[image]

[sample code](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/wRRmxV)

Comment: But the preview div is not displaying in Edge

Comment: after adding height 100% to preview. I am able to see the preview in edge. Thanks

Comment: You are mentioning the preview text or preview class? but both are displayed, added the output  and sample code check it out. sample code is not working in IE, just check the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` for IE to fill the available space

```
 min-height: 100%; in IE
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, min-height did the trick

```
min-height: -moz-available;
min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
min-height: fill-available;
```