# "Scrollbar not showing in 'firefox browser' css problem"

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

Scrollbar not showing in firefox browser but in chrome it is working fine below is the css code

```
::ng-deep .adf-search-fitler {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: none;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

[image: scrollbar missing image]
[image: inspect firefoxbrowser]

This -webkit-fill-available will work on chrome browser but "how to achieve the scrollbar 'firefox browser'"

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to the scrollbar, but `-webkit` prefixes only work in Webkit browsers. I believe Mozilla has it's own prefix `-moz-available`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887362/924299) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54175718/924299). Also see [Can I use fill-available?](https://caniuse.com/#search=fill-available).

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple height properties:

```
::ng-deep .adf-search-fitler {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: -moz-available;
  height: fill-available;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: none;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

To explain it -moz will be ignored by chrome and vice versa.